# Javascript JSON.parse returns nothing

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

So i'm trying to parse this json with javascript and it reads it from the webpage correctly however it just freezes when reaching the JSON.parse.

Here's what the webpage outputs:

```
{
Players: 18,
maxPlayers: 32,
Map: "jb_summer_redux_v3"
}
```

Here's what the full code is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://in.nickparksdev.com/info.php";
document.write("Loading....");
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    document.write(xhr.responseText);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    document.write("Test: " + jsonResponse.Players);
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

Here's what that document.write(xhr.responseText); outputs:

```
{"Players":19,"maxPlayers":32,"Map":"jb_summer_redux_v3"}
```

Any help on this would be great :)

Comment: Does the webpage put quotes around `Players`, `maxPlayers`, and `Map`? The first part of your question says it doesn't, but the `xhr.responseText` shows that it does.

Comment: What happens if you use `console.log()` instead of `document.write()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page return HTML not JSON

Output :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS Players</title>

</head>

<body>
{"Players":15,"maxPlayers":32,"Map":"jb_summer_redux_v3"}</body>
</html>
```

You have to output only the JSON not HTML.

Comment: He might have noticed this if he'd used `console.log()` instead of `document.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, JSON.parse does return the correct object from that string.  However, your file is HTML with JSON in it.